# Disabling IRQ #11

Tags: boot, grub2

I am kind of a noob with linux. I know simple commands like sudo apt-get and things like that. But I have been having problems with my computer. a lot of times I will start my computer and it will start saying: `Nobody cared. Boot with IRQpoll option.` Then it will keep saying `Disabling IRQ #11` and I don't know how to enable the IRQpoll option. I have read other forums and they say to edit your `/boot/grub/menu.lst` and add another code to it or something like that. But when I open it, there's nothing in the document..
To open the document, I open the Terminal and type in `gksu gedit /boot/grub/menu.lst`

Comment: if you are using ubuntu, what version of it are you using ? can you add the content of the file `/etc/default/grub`.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: can you post the content of `/etc/default/grub`

Comment: When I open that file is has this in it:

Comment: Wait.. It wont let me post it all.

Comment: put the file content here http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/ and edit your question with a the link given